# jq: Filter by node at arbitrary place

Tags: json, filter, jq

JSONPath has an expression to filter by node at arbitrary place `$..node`, which like `//node` in `xpath`. Is there any way to do that in `jq`?

Using https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/#result5 as example

`$ curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5'`

Here is the data & result for JSONPath `$..commit.committer`:

[image]

How to do the same in (/translate to) `jq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
[..|objects|.commit.committer//empty]
```

- [Recursive Descent: `..`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RecursiveDescent:..),
- [`objects`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars),
- [Alternative Operator: `//`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://),
- [`empty`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#empty).

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is `..` (that is an alias to the `recurse` function).

You can use it like this:

```
curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=5' \
   |jq 'map(..|.commit?.committer//empty)'
```

The `..` function goes recursively through the whole JSON path returning every single element.

The `.commit?` looks for fields with name `commit` and drop the other.

The last part selects the `committer` object and do not show `null` if there isn't any.

Comment: You're example isn't similar to OP's one. Losing the first level doesn't matter in the given example.